# How to call GNU ReadLine in Genie

Tags: python, vala, genie

I know the stdin.read_line() function, but I wanted to make my code less verbose via the use or something more in line to raw_input() in python.

So I found out about GNU ReadLine in [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.vala/2261) discussion about vala, however I can`t reproduce it in Genie.

The python code that I want to mimic is:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    response = raw_input("Enter something or 'quit' to end => ")
    if response == 'quit':
        print 'quitting'
        loop = 0
    else:
        print 'You typed %s' % response
```

The far I could get was:

```
[indent=4]

init
    var loop = 1
    while loop == 1
        // print "Enter something or 'quit' to end => "
        var response = ReadLine.read_line("Enter something or 'quit' to end => ")
        if response == "quit"
            print "quitting"
            loop = 0
        else 
            print "You typed %s", response
```

And tried to compile with:

```
valac --pkg readline -X -lreadline loopwenquiry.gs
```

But I am getting the error:

```
loopwenquiry.gs:7.24-7.31: error: The name `ReadLine' does not exist in the context of `main'
        var response = ReadLine.read_line("Enter something or 'quit' to end => ")
                       ^^^^^^^^
loopwenquiry.gs:7.22-7.81: error: var declaration not allowed with non-typed initializer
        var response = ReadLine.read_line("Enter something or 'quit' to end => ")
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
loopwenquiry.gs:8.12-8.19: error: The name `response' does not exist in the context of `main'
        if response == "quit"
           ^^^^^^^^
loopwenquiry.gs:12.35-12.42: error: The name `response' does not exist in the context of `main'
            print "You typed %s", response
                                  ^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It's `Readline` not `ReadLine` (note the difference in case).

Comment: BTW: Why don't you just write your own `raw_input` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment from Jens the namespace is Readline, not ReadLine. The function is also readline, not read_line. So your working code would be:

```
[indent=4]
init
    while true     
        response:string = Readline.readline("Enter something or 'quit' to end => ")
        if response == "quit"
            print "quitting"
            break
        else
            print "You typed %s", response
```

I notice you use `valac --pkg readline -X -lreadline loopwenquiry.gs` to compile, which is good. The `-X -lreadline` tells the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) to use the `readline` library. In most cases you won't need to do this because there is a [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) file, these have a `.pc` file extension, that contains all the necessary information. It looks as though someone has [submitted a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2014-05/msg00000.html) to fix this to the readline library. So using `-X -llibrary_i_am_using` should be the exception as most libraries have a `.pc` file.

I have also used `while..break` for the infinite loop to see if you think that is a slightly clearer style.

Comment: I appreciate your throughout responses, thanks for the while..break loop. That is an enhancement to the code. AIThomas, what is the best way to know when to add a uses command (similar to import) at the beginning of the code, and how to find out whether my code needs a --pkg argument to compile properly? Why in this example I didn't have to add something like: uses GNUReadline?

Comment: 'uses' isn't import as such it is just using a namespace. You could rewrite the above code with 'uses Readline' and then change 'Readline.readline' to just 'readline' because you have now included everything in the Readline namespace. Saves a bit of typing. If you don't use 'uses' then you just have to prefix everything with the binding's namespace. --pkg is the "import" and you will need to use it in all cases. Genie is set up to use --pkg glib-2.0 and --pkg gobject-2.0 automatically. Use --verbose with valac to see this in action.

Comment: I've also written this up in the docs - see https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie#Using_a_C_Library